# phpMyAdmin doesnt access session variables

Tags: mysql, sql, session, phpmyadmin, session-variables

So when I create a session variable in a query in phpmyadmin like this:

```
SET @myname = 'Jake';
SELECT @myname;
```

Which creates a sessionvariable which should be alive until my connection disconects and so should be accessible from other skripts.

Then I run an other script to access the same session variable:

```
SELECT @myname;
```

And then I get 'null' as a result.

But I would like to have access to the session variable I have created in a script from an other.

So I assume phpmyadmin eather creates a new connection at every run of a script or somehow doesnt allow access to session variables. But I am new to phpmyadmin so I dont know.

Thanks for your answeres.

Comment: _"I assume phpmyadmin eather creates a new connection at every run of a script"_ <- this

Comment: do you know a solution for this?